# Segues not executing when run using Swift and Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, verification

So I've set up my app to determine if there is a user and what to do if there is or is not. Also if they have verified their account (via phone number and sms) my issue is that when I run the app nothing happens. It loads and then just doesn't perform any of the segues. All segue identifiers are named correctly. currentUser variable has a value but numberIsVerified has no value. Im sure that has something to do with it but  not sure what or how to fix it.

Code to determine where to take the user:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

    if currentUser == nil || currentUser!["phoneNumberVerified"] == nil {

        performSegueWithIdentifier("showInitialView", sender: self)

    } else {

        if let numberIsVerified = currentUser!["phoneNumberVerified"] as? Bool {

            if currentUser != nil && numberIsVerified == false {
                performSegueWithIdentifier("showVerifyUserView", sender: self)

            } else if currentUser != nil && numberIsVerified == true {
                performSegueWithIdentifier("showMyEventsView", sender: self)

            } else {
                performSegueWithIdentifier("showInitialView", sender: self)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I checked it out but doesn't seem to be the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use `performSegueWithIdentifier` when your view is fully loaded. So you can't segue from viewDidLoad. To fix this, move your segue to viewDidAppear:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

}
```

---

update: i created a simple application that performs the segue for you to compare your code to:

[download project](http://beaulieu.blob.core.windows.net/images/General/20151219063410derp.zip)

Comment: @m1234 remove all of your logic and just test the segue once to see if it's a segue problem or a logic problem. edit: but for sure, you can't segue from viewDidLoad

Comment: I tried every segue copying the name from the identifier name on the starboard and none worked

Comment: @m1234 I've created and uploaded a project for you to compare your code to, try moving the segue from viewDidLoad to viewWillAppear. Good luck

Comment: Thanks! I moved it to viewDidAppear like in your project and it worked! Also your comments says to move to viewWillAppear but in your project its in viewDidAppear just so you know